# transferred computers with Android Studio and now have Gradle error

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I had a gradle error at first where I needed to change the version. I read about this problem on the android studio website, and I followed there directions and changed this line in the gradle file:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.0'
```

My error didnt go away and my main was full of red underlines. I then restarted Android Studio and everything seemed fixed.

But when I tried to compile and run on my phone from my mac book air I got this error:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'BeerPortfolioPro'.
> The SDK directory '/Users/Mike/Library/Caches/AndroidStudioPreview/compile-server/"/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk"' does not exist.
```

my gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the dependency to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.4'`.

Also, add a local.properties file in the project root folder with a line pointing to the Android Studio sdk directory. I had to put this line:

`sdk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk`

Comment: You also don't have a a repositories section for your project. Right now, it's just for the build. Taken from the developer website:
`Note: This only affects the code running the build, not the project. The project itself needs to declare its own repositories and dependencies. This will be covered later.`

Comment: OK I changed my one line to read: com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.4 and still get the same error. Not sure where to put that other line you gave me.

Comment: You need to create a new file, local.properties, in the project root folder. It's just a text file with the sdk location. You may need to change the path to point to where your sdk is located.